# Get value and name of property of an object

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I'm trying to build some objects based on properties coming from another object. The class of the objects I need to build is

```
public class Data
{
    public string Attribute { get; set; }
    public string Value{ get; set; }
}
```

And the attribute will be the name of the property (and the value its value)

So I was trying to use Expressions trees to make a method that I can use for avoiding hard coding that attribute

Up to the moment I came to these couple of methods, based on a couple of posts I was reading on the net

```
public static string GetName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> e)
{
    var member = (MemberExpression)e.Body;
    return member.Member.Name;
}

public static Data BuildData<T>(Expression<Func<T>> e, appDetailCategory category)
{
    var member = (MemberExpression)e.Body;
    Expression strExpr = member.Expression;

    var name = member.Member.Name;
    var value = Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(strExpr).Compile()();

    return new Data
    {
        Attribute = name,
        Value = value
    };
}
```

But the line I'm trying to set the value raises an exception:

```
Expression of type 'AutomapperTest.Program+DecisionRequest' cannot be used for return type 'System.String'
```

I'm pretty sure this message it's supposed to make the error obvious but it's not for me

UPDATE:

I'm calling it this way

```
private static Data[] GetApplicatonDetailsFromRequest(DecisionRequest request)
{
        BuildData(() => request.PubID)

        //...

}
```

Comment: It looks like the method represented by `strExpr` does not have a `string` return type, as expected by the Lambda.Compile().  Can you constrain the generic `T` type of the `e` parameter, or replace the `<string>` in the Lambda.Compile with `<T>`?

Comment: You do not wish to hardcode. But how about reading you object and converting into json string and converting it back to a dynamic object?

Comment: Thanks @MikeofSST, I've updated how I'm calling it, I was expecting that to return directly a string as that property is a string

Comment: I see your point @theinsaneone, thanks. Thing is that I need to map other bunch of properties that don't fit into this data type and can be mapped directly so for them would be kid of going back and forward wouldn't it?

Comment: The stack trace of the exception will most likely make it much easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be **member**, not **member.Expression**.

```
    public static Data BuildData<T>(Expression<Func<T>> e, appDetailCategory category)
    {
        var member = (MemberExpression)e.Body;

        var name = member.Member.Name;
        var value = Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(member).Compile()();

        return new Data
        {
            Attribute = name,
            Value = value
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is that the type of `PubID` isn't a string. You've got two options, either change `Data` to store the value as an `object` or call `ToString` on the value returned from the property and store it. For example:

```
public static Data BuildData<T>(Expression<Func<T>> e)
{
    var member = (MemberExpression)e.Body;
    var name = member.Member.Name;

    Func<T> getPropertyValue=e.Compile();
    object value = getPropertyValue();

    return new Data
    {
        Attribute = name,
        Value = value.ToString()
    };
}
```

Note that to get the value you can just compile the `Func` expression.